# .muttrc and gnome-keyring

Tags: linux, mutt, gnome-keyring

I'm trying to use gnome-keyring-query to avoid hard-coding my Gmail password in my .muttrc.
According to http://www.df7cb.de/blog/2010/Using_multiple_IMAP_accounts_with_Mutt.html the following lines in .muttc should do:

```
set my_PW = 'gnome-keyring_query get google'
set imap_pass = $my_PW
```

However putting this into my .muttrc, I don't get asked for my keyring password, but mutt just says "Authentication failed".

I tried gnome-keyring-query get google on the command line and it behaves like I would expect, i.e. a window pops up asking for the keyring password and then it prints my Google password to the command line.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake was to use

> ' '

instead of

> ` `

in the first line.